# Why can't I center an inline flex-item?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm creating navigation bars using flexbox and ran into this particular issue when trying to create buttons out of anchor tags (i.e. link in the centre of a box).

I have the `li` set to display flex so I can centre the `a`, but as soon as I give the `a` some height, the `a` aligns to the top-left. Is there any way of getting the `a` centred?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font: sans-serif;
}

#top-nav {
  border-bottom: 4px solid blue;
}

#center-section {
  display: flex;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}

#center-section>* {
  flex: 1 1 0;
}

header section {
  background: blue;
  height: 90px;
  width: 500px;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
}

.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  align-self: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.navbar ul li {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  background-color: yellow;
  align-self: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="top-nav">
    <div id="center-section">
      <section id="logo">
        <a href="">Home</a>
      </section>
      <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Store</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you set height:100% to `a` you make it stretch all the `li` and thus you can no more control it as all the alignment are equivalent in this case. What you need is to align the content **inside** the `a`. For this you can make it a flex container and use `align-items` and/or `justify-content`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font: sans-serif;
}

#top-nav {
  border-bottom: 4px solid blue;
}

#center-section {
  display: flex;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}

#center-section>* {
  flex: 1 1 0;
}

header section {
  background: blue;
  height: 90px;
  width: 500px;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
}

.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  align-self: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.navbar ul li {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  background-color: yellow;
  display:inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="top-nav">
    <div id="center-section">
      <section id="logo">
        <a href="">Home</a>
      </section>
      <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Store</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```